# How to put a test.txt in your CMake to test your program?

Tags: c, clion

So I am using CLion on a Mac and wrote my code and would like to test it. I have an input file called test.txt. I know how to do it using terminal which is simply `./a < test.txt` and it will run the binary and take `text.txt` as input. My question is, can we do it through CMake? So that I don't need to use terminal and just press the "run" button in CLion.

Answer (score 0):

Having:

```
add_executable(a ...)
```

The short workaround on systems with `sh` shell would be to just spawn a shell to do the redirection:

```
add_test(NAME atest COMMAND sh -c "\"$1\" < \"$2\"" -- $<TARGET_FILE:a> test.txt)
```

A proper way would be to use CMake instead of shell. So a separate CMake script to run the executable with redirected file. Below is an example that just creates the script from inside CMake - but it can be just a separate file instead.

```
# redirect_stdin_from_file.cmake
  execute_process(
    COMMAND "${COMMAND}"
    INPUT_FILE "${INPUT_FILE}"
    RESULT_VARIABLE ret
  )
  if(ret)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "ERROR: ${COMMAND} failed: ${ret}")
  endif()

# CMakeLists.txt
add_test(NAME atest2 COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    -D COMMAND=$<TARGET_FILE:a>
    -D INPUT_FILE=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.txt
    -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/redirect_stdin_from_file.cmake
)
```